# Error signing user in with Umbraco Membership

Tags: registration, umbraco, membership-provider

After setting the auth ticket from a successful login with the umbraco membership provider, the Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated remains false.

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(uname, pwd))
 {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uname, true);
 }
```

Config:

```
 <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="WebsiteUser" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just started working after rebooting the server... mystery...